# Does Scheme work with Microsoft COM?

Tags: oop, com, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm new to Scheme and I like it a lot for its first-class/higher-order functions. However, my data comes from a COM source with an object-oriented API.

I know Scheme and COM belong to different programming paradigms, but I'm wondering if there is any interface or a way for Scheme to connect to a COM source?

Comment: sounds like you're looking for COM/ActiveX bindings for Scheme (suggest you try searching for those keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MIT-Scheme, it looks like there are some low-level Win32 primitives but nothing for supporting COM/ActiveX. Looks like you can [access DLL functions via a "Foreign Function Interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Win32-Package-Reference.html#Win32-Package-Reference)"

See also "[How can I interface to COM/ActiveX, CORBA, EJB?](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards)" on the schemewiki.org, which claims that [PLT-Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/) has COM/ActiveX bindings.

Comment: Yes, PLT Scheme (now called Racket) has both a [COM](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mzcom/) interface and an [ActiveX](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mysterx/) one.